# No sound (After I removed Pulseaudio)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, soundcard, purge

1. When I open a video file it says "Audio output failed:
   The audio device "default" could not be used:
   No such file or directory."
2. When Im trying to record sound in Audacity it says "Error opening recording device. Error code 0 success.

How it started:

I tried to tune my mic, heard that "pulseaudio" can be used for it.
I Installed pulseaudio and it flooded my applications menu with 121 (yes I actually counted them) garbage spam programs with "LSP" on their icons.
Also pulseaudio messed up my mic so from now on I had tiny skips all over my recordings (as a bonus, keep the change sir)

Its been a long HELL to find out how to remove it and I wasted like a half of my work day, but I finally removed pulseaudio and its 121 applications. This helped:

```
sudo apt remove lsp-plugins ; sudo apt autoremove
```

However, after restarting, I see that I have no sound at all, its almost like if pulseaudio said: "you want to remove me? ok you can go to hell, no sound for you".

I know I did something wrong, and maybe some audio-card files were removed too?
please help.

Ubuntu version: 21.04

Motherboard: ASRock A320M-HDV R4.0 Socket AM4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling your sound card drivers or if you have any system backups try resetting your system. Your last resort option is to backup all your files and reinstall Ubuntu. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine:  sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio  -and then:  sudo alsa force-reload

Answer (score 1):

*The following answer was posted by the question's author as an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1355778/4) to the question:*

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo alsa force-reload
```